# Is there any way to handle promocode in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

"I have integrated the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin into my Flutter application for managing subscriptions and product purchases. Recently, I initiated promotional offers using promo codes generated from the Google Play Console to provide certain users with discounts on subscriptions and products.

Although the promo codes successfully apply discounts to purchases within the application, I've encountered an issue where these discounted purchases do not reflect in the Order Management section of the Google Play Console. Furthermore, I'm unable to capture these purchases within my application's past purchases listener, which is crucial for storing transaction data in Firebase Database using purchase order IDs.

Could someone kindly provide guidance on how to effectively manage promotional codes within a Flutter application, ensuring seamless integration with the in_app_purchase plugin and proper tracking of discounted purchases in both the Google Play Console and application database?"